# Can invoke interface implicit methods but not the explicit ones? (Interview Quest!on)

Tags: c#

(Interview Question)
Can you give me an example of an interface implemented in a class, in which you can invoke it's implicit methods but not the explicit ones?

Comment: Do you mean a class where you can't call the explicitly override interface methods?

Comment: What do you mean by implicit and explicit methods in the class that has implemented the interface? Do you mean access modifiers like public and private?

Comment: @Mharlin No I mean the implicitly and explicitly implemented interface methods in the class.

Comment: By the way this is an interview question ... and it has an answer.

Comment: There is a situation where it does not work. If you think out side your assembly!

Comment: If your interface is public and your class is public, why should it not work across assemblies?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Who said the interface is public? ;) .. Could you write the example were it won't work for an internal interface please?

Comment: If you declare `internal interface` or just `interface`, it will be internal and only accessible inside the assembly where it is declared. Otherwise you have to declare it as `public interface`. This has nothing to do implicit or explicit implementation at all. The example I gave below works only internally. If you put `public` in front of the interface and the class, you can use them everywhere.

Comment: One Project creates one assembly. You can have more than one project in a solution. If you want to test the situations above, Create a library project with interfaces and classes (this creates a dll). In the main project set a project reference to the library project. Try to access internal and public interfaces, classes and members from the main project and you will see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

Assembly 1:

```
internal interface IFlyable 
{
    void Fly();
}

public class Bird: IFlyable 
{
    public void Fly() { ... }
    void IFlyable.Fly() { ... }
}
```

Assembly 2:

```
Bird bird = new Bird();
bird.Fly();
((IFlyable)bird).Fly() // Error, IFlyable is internal
```

It was an interview question. Smart one if you think about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
interface IA
{
    void Method1();
    void Method2();
    void Method3();
}

class A : IA
{
    // Implicit implementation
    public void Method1()
    {
    }

    // Explicit implementation
    void IA.Method2()
    {
    }

    // Implicit + explicit implementation!
    public void Method3()
    {
    }

    void IA.Method3()
    {
    }
}

class TestImplicitExplicit
{
    public void Test( )
    {
        A a = new A();
        a.Method1(); // ok
        //a.Method2(); // does not compile
        a.Method3(); // ok

        IA ia = a;
        ia.Method1(); // ok
        ia.Method2(); // ok
        ia.Method3(); // ok (calls another method than a.Method3(); !)
    }
}
```

The explicit implementation is only seen through the interface.

Comment: you still were able to call Method2 when you declared ia or type IA. So it is doable? Can you think of a situation where you cannot do this?

Comment: It should always work. Oddly enough, you can even have an explicit and an implicit implementation of the same method at the same time!

Comment: Explain or give an example, please!

Comment: Example in the question above.

Comment: You can call `IFlyable.Fly()` with `((IFlyable)bird).Fly();` or as I have shown in my example: `IFlyable ib = bird; ib.Fly();`. However only in the current assembly, since `IFlyable` is internal; but this has nothing to do with implicit or explicit implementation, only with `internal` and `public`.

Comment: That's what I'm saying!!! The question was to give an example .. and when the interface is internal and the implementing class is called from out side the assembly; you can call the implicit method but not the explicit. (Simple interview question but clever!)